# Rex-Ray volume won't share with other EC2 servers

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

I have a two EC2 server and I wanted to create volume from **aws EBS** which should be available for both server. So I used **REx-Ray plugin** for this.

steps I did:

1. install

   docker plugin install rexray/ebs REXRAY_PREEMPT=true EBS_ACCESSKEY=*** EBS_SECRETKEY=***
2. create volume

   docker volume create -d rexray/ebs --name mongo_vol -o=volumeType=io1 -o=size=100 -o=iops=100

When I ran **docker volume ls** in first EC2 server shows result like this;

> DRIVER             VOLUME NAME
>
> rexray/ebs:latest   External MongoDB Data
>
> rexray/ebs:latest   MySQL
>
> rexray/ebs:latest   Private MongoDB
>
> **rexray/ebs:latest   mongo_vol**

But when I ran docker volume ls in my second server that shows result like this:

> DRIVER             VOLUME NAME
>
> **local   mongo_vol**

My driver have not change, but volume name shows in both side.

I could not find anything related this on internet when do my research about this.

Does anyone give me a idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a issue like this. Rex-ray make EBS accessible to both server, I think you have install rexy-ray into one server.

> Install Rex-Ray into your other server as well.

that won't fix your issue, Next,

> Remove **local driver** volume in your other server

before remove volume, make a *backup* or *snapshot* of your volume in case.

Answer (score 0):

EBS volumes can only be attached to one EC2 instance at a time. If you need storage that is accessible to both servers simultaneously, you can use EFS and the REX-Ray EFS driver.